# How to access array created from a struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I made a struct called cities and outside of the struct I created an array of type cities with its parameters. I am trying to access that array but it is not working out for me. Would appreciate any help!

```
public struct cities
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int windSpeed;
    public string nameCity;

    public cities(int _x, int _y, int _windSpeed, string _nameCity)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        windSpeed = _windSpeed;
        nameCity = _nameCity;
    }


}


cities[] citywinds =
{
    new cities(171,197,1,"Goodland"),
    new cities(422,195,1,"Hill City"),
    new cities(796,239,1,"Manhattan"),
    new cities(908,243,1,"Topeka"),
    new cities(941,490,1,"Chanute"),
    new cities(706,475,1,"Wichita"),
    new cities(389,450,1,"Dodge City"),
    new cities(281,418,1,"Garden City"),
    new cities(997,110,1,"Cameron"),
    new cities(1044,361,1,"El Dorado Springs"),
    new cities(1024,577,1,"Monett"),
    new cities(749,575,1,"Ponca City"),
    new cities(720,95,1,"Beatric"),
    new cities(452,92,1,"Kearney"),
    new cities(457,573,1,"West Woodward"),
    new cities(128,568,1,"Elkhart"),
    new cities(120,88,1,"Akron")
};


citywinds[1]._windspeed; //not working
```

Comment: So this was an exercise in pasting your actual code. and the actual error messages, even with the best assumptions it was still hard to work what the actual problem was

Comment: Indentation and naming conventions are helpful in understanding the code.

Comment: Also unlike `C`, in `CSharp` all items need to be declared inside a class. Your `citywinds` variable is just handing out there in the air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are prefixing with an underscore

```
citywinds[1]._windspeed
```

where the property is

```
public int windSpeed;
```

Try this

```
var speed = citywinds[1].windSpeed;
```

you will also need to mark `cities[] citywinds` as `static` if it is a class member. Which is likely your other problem

```
static cities[] citywinds
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JAkAwk)

Comment: @Araasai the above should work, unless this is not your code

Comment: I put this "int x = citywinds[1].windspeed;"    and I am getting this error message           "field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field "

Comment: same error with "var speed = citywinds[1].windspeed;"

Comment: Well, you are expected to put that code in a method. You can't just chuck it anywhere.

Comment: @Araasai Ahh ok, yeah it was assumed your code was in your method, not a class member, updated again, with demo

Comment: @John thanks for that, was more than a little confused

Comment: if you define citywinds inside the main, you dont have to worry about adding a static modifier but if you create it as a global variable (outside the Main), you will need to create it static since you are accessing it from within the `Main` thats declared static.

Comment: @Araasai what Jawad said

Comment: @Araasai please do mark the relevant post as answer